# html5 video change src tags via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, video

I know that I missed out the (mp4, ogv), but I've not idea how to add them on my function.

- My html5 video works only on Chrome and Firefox (webm). Unfortunately Safari and IE don't work.
- How can I implement the other extensions (mp4, ogv)?

```js
$.fn.videoLoop = function (options) {
  var video = $(this),
  videoEl = video.get(0),
  selVideoIdx = 0;

  options = options || {};

  var playlist = options.playlist || [],
  poster = options.poster || "http://placehold.it/1024x768/FFFFFF/FFFFFF";

if (playlist.length > 1) {
  video.attr('src', playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length]);
  video.attr('poster', poster);
  video.attr('autoload', true);
  selVideoIdx++;

  video.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
      videoEl.currentTime = 0.5;
      videoEl.play();
  }).bind('ended', function () {
      videoEl.src = playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length];
      videoEl.loop = true;
      videoEl.load();
    });
  }
};

$(function () {
  $('#start').videoLoop({
    'playlist' : [
        '../assets/video-start/HOMEPAGE_Walk_In_v01_(Converted).webm',
        '../assets/video-loop/HOMEPAGE_Loop_v01_(Converted).webm'],
    'poster' :  "../assets/video-loop/Screen-Shot.jpg"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-start target">
  <video id="start">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: If you implement multiple video resource urls in source tag, "The browser will use the first recognized format." as the document says:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: @hitokun_s I perfectly know that. I'm using 2 videos, so the best solution is the mine above. I need to make that function to recognise the format!

Comment: I should have read your post more carefully, sorry. I understood what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like that?
I used an array of media in a video obj in order to handle several video formats.

```js
(function($)
{$.fn.videoLoop = function (options) {
    
 function changeVideoSrc(vidObj,vidEl){
     vidEl.html("");
     vidObj.media.forEach(function(obj){
         console.log(obj);
         vidEl.append($("<source>").attr("src",obj.src).attr("type",obj.format));
     });
 }
    
  var video = this,
  videoEl = video[0],
  selVideoIdx = 0;

  options = options || {};

  var playlist = options.playlist || [],
  poster = options.poster || "http://placehold.it/1024x768/FFFFFF/FFFFFF";

if (playlist.length > 1) {
  var firstvid = playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length];
  changeVideoSrc(firstvid,video);
  video.attr('poster', poster);
  video.attr('autoload', true);
  video.attr('autoplay', true);
  selVideoIdx++;

  video.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
      videoEl.currentTime = 0.5;
      videoEl.play();
  }).bind('ended', function () {
      var currentvid = playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length];
      changeVideoSrc(currentvid,video);
      videoEl.loop = true;
      videoEl.load();
      selVideoIdx++;
    });
  }
};


 
var video1 = {};
video1.title = 'w3schools';
video1.media = [{'format':'video/mp4','src':'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4'},{'format':'video/ogg','src':'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg'}];
 
var video2 = {};
video2.title = 'w3.org';
video2.media = [{'format':'video/mp4','src':'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4'},{'format':'video/ogg','src':'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv'}];

var data = {};
data.playlist = [video1,video2];
data.poster = "http://placehold.it/1024x768/000000/FFFFFF"


$('#start').videoLoop(data);

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-start target">
  <video id="start" width="400" height="300" controls>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what I was after, just need to check if it works with my loop video, are u there?

Comment: In my exemple the two videos should play in loop, what do you want to do precisely?

Comment: this work amazingly but on IE i got black screen/jumps do you know why?